# Why 'ChangeNotifier' has O(n^2) time when dispatching notification in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

Looking into Flutter doc about [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html).

It stated that

> ChangeNotifier is optimized for small numbers (one or two) of listeners. It is O(N) for adding and removing listeners and O(N²) for dispatching notifications (where N is the number of listeners).

So how's the dispatching notification make O(n^2) time complexity? I already dig into ChangeNotifier and ValueListenableBuilder source code.

**Update:**

No more O(n^2) complex while dispatching listener.

> It is O(1) for adding listeners and O(N) for removing listeners and dispatching notifications (where N is the number of listeners).

New document in [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html).

Comment: this is because of that line: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/0b8abb4724/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart#L205 - notice that they double check if `listener` is not removed in response to a notification

Comment: Oh. I don't recognize that line. Thank you

Comment: sure, your welcome